Angular Module Federation NullInjectorError
I've initiated an NX project with Module Federation and Angular. I have 2 remotes and 1 shell application, along those application I also have 2 shared libraries: ui-common and util-common. In my shared service called TranslationService I use a service TranslateService from a library called @ngx-translate.
Every application (shell and remotes) uses a bootstrap function to bootstrap the application with an app.config.ts file:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, appConfig).catch((err) =>
  console.error(err)
);

All of my app.config.ts files provide the NgxTranslateRoutesModule containing the TranslateService like so:
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [
    provideZoneChangeDetection({eventCoalescing: true}),
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom([
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
        defaultLanguage: 'en',
        useDefaultLang: true,
        loader: {
          provide: TranslateLoader,
          useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
          deps: [HttpClient],
        },
      }),
      NgxTranslateRoutesModule.forRoot()
    ]),
}

When running my remotes isolated, everything works fine. When running my shell however, I get this error on bootstrap.ts:6 and core.mjs:6620.
NullInjectorError: NullInjectorError: No provider for TranslateService!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:1660:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3106:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:3106:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:1107:40)
    at ɵɵinject (core.mjs:1113:60)
    at inject (core.mjs:1199:12)
    at new TranslationService (translation.service.ts:15:37)
    at Object.TranslationService_Factory [as factory] (translation.service.ts:58:4)
    at core.mjs:3234:47
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (core.mjs:872:9)

I've injected this service in my TranslationService like this: private _translateService = inject(TranslateService); (using Angular 18).
Here comes the catch, when removing the 2 remotes from my module-federation.config.ts everything works as expected! But I have a feeling I need those so leaving these out feels very wrong to me:
import { ModuleFederationConfig } from '@nx/webpack';

const config: ModuleFederationConfig = {
  name: 'shell',
  remotes: [] // <--- Empty array (instead of ['remote1', 'remote2'])
};

export default config;

I can't with a good feeling remove these remotes from my shell module federation config. And I think it has something to do with sharing depencendies, but I can't get my head around it. Please help me.
What did I try:

Removed ties relating to the TranslateService in the code, error still persists. Which leads me to believe it might have something to do with the TranslateLoader.
Changed @ngx-translate/core to shared = false in the module federation.config, error still persists.
Provided the TranslateService instead of the module, circular depenceny error.
Removed node modules folder and reinstalled all dependencies.


Turns out, you should not put package-lock.json in your .gitignore file! Removing that line made the app run again.
